# How to add python-xbee receipes for yocto

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, yocto, bitbake

My *python-xbee-2.3.2.bb* file contains:

```
SRC_URI="https://github.com/niolabs/python-xbee/archive/v2.3.2.tar.gz"   
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "e74381e23f12159675d7ad92a06d8d0f"
DEPENDS += "${PYTHON_PN}-pytest-runner-native"
do_configure[noexec]="1"    

inherit setuptools

RDEPENDS_${PN} += " \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-subprocess "

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "\
    ${PYTHON_PN}-fcntl \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-numbers \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-shell \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-stringold \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-io \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-logging \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-math \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-netclient \
    ${PYTHON_PN}-threading "
```

**This is error getting when I compile `bitbake python-xbee-2.3.2`:**

> ERROR: python-xbee-2.3.2-1.0-r0 do_compile: 'python setup.py build '
>   execution failed. ERROR: python-xbee-2.3.2-1.0-r0 do_compile: Function
>   failed: do_compile (log file is located at
>   /home/chandra/yoctorpi/mender-raspberrypi/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-xbee-2.3.2/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.15930)
>   ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
>   /home//build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-xbee-2.3.2/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.15930

**After that am getting log data follows**:

> can't open file 'setup.py':[Errno 2] No such file or directory. 
>   /home//build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-xbee-2.3.2/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python-native/python: can't open file  'setup.py' :[Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   **ERROR:** 'python setup.py build ' execution failed
>   **ERROR:** Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home//build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-xbee-2.3.2/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.15930)
>   **ERROR:** Task (/home//build/../sources/poky/meta/recipes-support/python-xbee-2.3.2/python-xbee-2.3.2.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit pypi bbclass as well since this deals with python package installation:

```
inherit pypi
```

As a side notes:

1. Check how you assign **RDEPENDS_${PN}**, it looks that you just override it instead of updating.
2. The name of recipe according to [standard](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/OEManual/recipes_versioning.html) should python-xbee**_**2.3.2.bb - note the underscore (assuming your package supports only python2.X).
3. It's not recommended to hard-code version in SRC_URI, check in the above link as well.